# Rename files from different to same name with different extension

Tags: windows-10, script, rename, batch-rename

I have 12 folders with each containing two subfolders: "Images" & "Json". Now each "Images" folder has 10 image files named from 1.png to 10.png and each "Json" folder has 10 files named from 1.json to 10.json.

So in total I have 120 images and 120 json files. I want to randomize them and rename them into one folder for images and one folder for json files, so I will have 1.png to 120.png in one folder (order to be randomized) and same for the json files.

Each json file is connected to the image file so renaming of 1.png and 1.json should be to the same name.

I tried renaming like this but since I am not good at scripting I don't know how to perform exactly like above requirement:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.png') do (    
    ren %%a ArbitraryString!count!.png
    set /a count+=1    
)
```

and this

```
$i=1
Get-ChildItem | ForEach {    
        Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("filename" + $i + ".jpg")
        $i++    
}
```

I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command:

```
'\Main\folder\' | ForEach-Object{$($_ + "\*.png"), $($_ + "\*.json")} | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach { If ( $_.extension -ne $prevExt ) { $i=1 } Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension); $prevExt = $_.extension; }
```

```
Note: 
The files will be renamed in the source folder. It would be interesting to make a backup before running the above command.
```

Command comments:

```
'\Main\folder\'                                                - is the path where the folder with all your files is.
The symbol |                                                   - it's called a pipeline, it's a concatenation command to join several functions in one line.
ForEach-Object                                                 - you are defining which file extensions you will want to change the names of.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse                                         - will search for all files in folders and subfolders.
foreach                                                        - will execute the command to rename the files until the last one found.

{ If ( $_.extension -ne $prevExt ) { $i=1 }                    - will compare the current file extension, with the extension that was read previously,
                                                                 the { $i=1 } is resetting the value of the counter which will be the sequential name of the file 
                                                                 when the extension changes.
                                                                 Eg: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png... 1.json, 2.json, 3.json... that is, when the extension changes, the 
                                                                 counter starts a new sequence.

Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension) - Rename-Item    - is the command that will do the renaming of the files
                                                                 $_.FullName    - is the full name of the file
                                                                 -NewName       - is what name the file will be changed to, inside the parentheses are the parameters 
                                                                                  of the new file name: 
                                                                 '{0}'          - will be a file with numeric name
                                                                 -f $i++        - which will be added 1 to 1 
                                                                 +$_.extension  - keeping the original extension

$prevExt = $_.extension                                        - very important item: 
                                                                 this is where the extension of the file being seen is updated with the extension read, so that the command 
                                                                 Rename-Item can know when the file extension has changed and start the next name with numering starting from 1.
```

To rename and copy all files together to another folder:

```
$fileRenamed = "C:\MyRenamedPngJsonFolder\"
foreach ($e in $("png","json")) {ls 'C:\MyOriginalPngJsonFolder' -r -filt *.$e | % {$i=1} { copy $_.FullName $("$fileRenamed"+$i+"."+$e) -Recurse; $i++}}
```

The files will be renamed in the output folder as follows:

```
1.json 1.png, 2.json 2.png, 3.json 3.png, 4.json 4.png, 5.json 5.png...
```

Note: You can create the renamed files folder anywhere on your computer.
The files in the source folder will not be renamed.

I did some tests with the command above and realized that when there are already files in the output folder, they are overwritten by new files and end up being lost.

I made a more complete script and according to your need. The script checks if there are json and png files in the input folder, checks if the output folder already exists and if it doesn't, it automatically creates the folder. If the folder already exists, it will take the last existing sequential number in the folder and continue renaming from this last number so that the files do not overlap.

Note:

With this script you can put other file extensions in the folder and it will only convert png and json files.

This script will create an output_renamed_files_png_json folder with two subfolders for the renamed files.
eg. output_renamed_files_png_json\JSON PNG.

The renamed files will be copied to the folder according to their extension. 
eg. output_renamed_files_png_json\JSON  1.json, 2.json, 3.json...
output_renamed_files_png_json\PNG   1.png, 2.png, 3.png...

1.json 1.png, 2.json 2.png... are referring to each other as you reported in this post.

see script below:

```
$p=$j=0
$countyp = (ls 'path\original_files\*' -Recurse -Include *.json, *.png | Measure-Object ).Count;             # Checks that there are json and png files in the input folder before starting the process         
$files=Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'path\original_files\*' -Include *.json, *.png | Where {! $_.PSIsContainer } | # and select files if they exist.
% { { $_.extension }
If ($countyp -ne 0) 
   {                                                                                                         
      If ($_.extension -eq ".png")                                                                           # Counts the amount of JSON and PNG files.
   { 
      $p++
   }
   If ($_.extension -eq ".json") 
   { 
      $j++
   }     
 }
}
If ($countyp -eq 0) 
   {
    Write-Host "No PNG and JSON files found to be renamed!... type exit to finish and check for these files in the input folder." -foregroundcolor Red
    Exit
   }
If ($p -ne $j)                                                                                               # If the number of files are not the same, it shows a message informing you which file 
{                                                                                                            # extension is missing and its amount.

   If ($p -gt $j) 
      { 
        $tj=($p-$j)
        Write-Host "$tj JSON file(s) is missing from input folder!... type exit to finish and check input folder." -foregroundcolor Red   # Missing JSON extension message   
   }else {
        $tp=($j-$p)
        Write-Host "$tp PNG file(s) is missing from input folder!... type exit to finish and check input folder." -foregroundcolor Red    # Missing PNG extension message
      }
}else {                                                                                                     
$Folder = 'path\Renamed_Files_png_json'                                                             # checks if the output folder already exists. If it doesn't exist, it will create it.
   if ( -not (Test-Path -Path "$Folder") ) 
   {
      $null = (new-item -type directory -path 'path\Renamed_Files_png_json', 'path\Renamed_Files_png_json\JSON', 'path\Renamed_Files_png_json\PNG' -Force)      
   }
   $pathRenamed = 'path\Renamed_Files_png_json\'                                                    # Associates the output folder path to the variable.
   $count = ( Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File "$pathRenamed" | Measure-Object ).Count 
   If ( $count -eq 0)                                                                               # If the folder was just created, the json and png file numbering starts from 1.
   {
        $ip=$ij=1
   }
   else {                                                                                           # If the folder already exists, the files in the folders will be counted for the number 
   $ip=$ij=($count/2)+1                                                                             # starting from the last number of the existing file. As you informed that the files
   }                                                                                                # are always matched ( 1.json 1.png, 2.json 2.png), the total value is divided by 2.
   foreach ($e in $("png","json")) {
   ls 'path\original_files\' -r -filt *.$e | % {                                                    # Check the extension of files to copy them to the corresponding folder.
   If ( $_.extension -eq ".json" ) 
   {
     copy $_.FullName $("$pathRenamed"+$e+"\"+$ij+"."+$e) -Recurse -Force; $ij++ 
   }
   else {
     copy $_.FullName $("$pathRenamed"+$e+"\"+$ip+"."+$e) -Recurse -Force; $ip++ 
   }
  }
 } 
     Write-Host "The files have been renamed... type exit to finish!" -foregroundcolor Green
}
```

```
If you still haven't found a solution for your post, test it with the script!
```